# Heteroscedasticity in polynomial regression

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, polynomial

I am trying to establish a polynomial regression model to the following small dataset ([csv](https://files.fm/down.php?i=x96jxp8y&n=YC_poly.csv)).

```
        y           x  
.99601797   .99981704  
.99683697     .941906  
 .9999658   .99266339  
.99877053   .99606185  
.99900637   .99474346  
.99871661   .96773153  
.98961073   .99935843  
.99997705   .99489796  
 .9999985   .99941811  
.05619862   .65770998  
.07115553   .26205643  
.86786633   .67232541  
.37875096   .53353659  
.98989393   .78026009  
.97383714   .80477727  
.90647926   .73611526  
.53075677   .75069843  
.88723435   .36181755  
.13528064   .41102821  
 .1890786   .54261491  
.62188275   .37471297  
.69248789   .35577735  
.60087948   .31277366  
 .5877556   .25177197  
.41507422   .29997502  
.55983621   .45695137  
.71396721   .30077664  
 .6919711   .52495382  
  .680586   .58351367  
 .3231144   .41962059  
.94100567   .41007024  
.39398525   .28845982  
.93872696   .41620095  
.47853573   .24342891  
.62937088   .23825025  
.87075279   .23603982  
.85835464   .32599236  
 .8910219   .40700416  
.98383476   .33112953  
 .6129848   .33571762  
.40032955   .24112654  
.89572285   .39529544  
.99799395   .98989443  
.99948013   .95556783  
.99911476   .96960903  
.99690664   .96156409  
.31085976   .81125219  
.08901666   .53915165
```

After model fitting I end up with a polynomial regression model of the second order.

[image]

However, checking the residuals of the fitted model, I get serious warning signs regarding the variance of the residuals (heteroscedasticity).

[image: residual_plot_fitted_model]

Even though log transformation of the x variable improves the situation it can not fix all of the problems (seemingly).

[image: Residual_plot_xlog_transformed]

My question is the following: What is the way to go? HCSE (and if so on the log_transformed or the raw x model)? Is my dataset the problem and should I forget about regression models?

Comment: @NickCox 
I was limited by the files I could upload. Here is the basic x_y with the fitted function http://imgur.com/a/JPhOX
and here are the raw data
https://files.fm/u/ncwwakzx

Comment: The most striking thing in the plot of your raw data is that for high values of $x$ you appear to have hit a ceiling. I suspect this is what is driving the apparent quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

The diagnostic plots I don't see as obviously serious, particularly for a small sample where some quirkiness from small clusters of observations is likely. But passing a health check doesn't guarantee perfect health.

Perhaps the implication is that you would be happier with more variability of residuals for higher values of fitted, because then their variance would be about constant. Rather, the good news from *that plot alone* is that the fitted relationship is relatively well supported at high values.

But before a basic scatter plot with fitted function superimposed was posted, I did warn that

1. Sometimes when high values agree we're looking at approach to an asymptote and then polynomials may not be the best approach.
2. A quadratic can give a good fit but still be qualitatively wrong. How do you feel about a turning point somewhere in your fit?

Now that a scatter plot with fit superimposed has been posted, these warnings remain pertinent.

The major comment now is that the quadratic is unconvincing. I don't regard it as a plausible fit. For example, the fitted curve is steepest near $x = 1, y = 1$ in contrast to the data which if anything appear levelling off in that corner; and the quadratic shows a turning point at $x \approx 0.5$, which does not seem well supported by data nearby.

You seem to have two regimes:

(a) no obvious relationship between $x$ and $y$ for $x<0.9$

(b) $y \approx 1$ for $x>0.9$.

The two together don't to me suggest any obvious functional approximation.

What's the substantive story? Are there other predictors (covariates) that can help?

A meta-principle is that well-behaved residuals don't themselves validate a model. The model fit has to make sense (scientifically, practically, whatever). Concretely, a generating process such as $y = $ constant $+$ well-behaved noise will give well behaved residuals, but any relationship with $x$ is not thereby well defined. You appear to have more structure than that, but a better model is hard to suggest without some scientific or practical story.

The data seem strongly limited by [0, 1] on both axes. That suggests to me not a logarithmic transformation at all, but thinking on logit scale. A scatter plot may or may not be suggestive.

[image]